# Prolog: Get the fifth element from a list using only the append relation

Tags: list, prolog, append

My question is this:

Using only the append relation ( i.e. append (L1, L2, L3) ), formulate queries to determine the
following (Note although your answer should use `L3 = [ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 ]`it should work with any list
of five elements or more given as `L3`)

The queries I've tried so far are:

```
append(Left, [X|Y], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]).

append([W|X], [Y|Z], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]).
```

I don't see how its possible to get the fifth element of any given list using only the append relation. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can get the 5th element with `append/3`, but it's not as simple as just getting the element directly.  `append/3` is way overkill. So I suspect this is just an exercise in using `append/3`. Here's a hint: a list consisting of at least 3 elements can be written as `[X, Y, Z | T]`. Try at the Prolog prompt, for example, `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7] = [X, Y, Z | T]` and see what you get.

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out on my own using a similar method. My answer was: append([_|[_|[_|[_|[FifthElement|_]]]]],L2,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]).

Comment: You don't need all that. `[A|[B|[C|T]]]` is the same as `[A,B,C|T]`. Just `append([_,_,_,_,FifthElement], _, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])` or `append([_,_,_,_], [FifthElement|_], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])`. But that's overkill. You can just do `fifth_element([_,_,_,_,FifthElement|_], FifthElement)` and query it with, `fifth_element([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], X).`